# How to find a cycle between different groups of edges?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

For example, I have four groups of data in a list

```
{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, 
 {{3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 2}}, 
 {{4, 1}, {1, 4}, {1, 3}},
 {{2, 3}, {1, 5}}}
```

I want to find a directed cycle of size 4, with each edge from each group, the order of the group does not matter. In this case `{1, 2, 3, 4}` should be returned. My current brute force solution is to generate all the permutations of the rest $4-1$ groups and try if the last element is equal to the first element in the next list for any two adjacent groups. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: I was trying to come up with a good way to do this with coloured graph isomorphism, but I wasn't able to. The problem is that colours should be interchangeable (" the order of the group does not matter") which means that I have to generate too many different colourings for the cycle (4!/4 = 6 I think) before I match it. Then the solution is just not simple anymore.  Basically it's the same as yours.  So you might as well use `FindCycle` to find all cycles and then verify that the edges of the cycle are in different groups.

Comment: @Szabolcs my method is bad even after generating 3! Permutations. If you have a good method after that, I am very interested in learning it.

Comment: OK, I posted how I'd do it with FindCycles.  But I suggest you don't accept the answer and instead wait to see if people show better methods.  I am sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`FindCycle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCycle.html) and then filter out those cycles where the four edges are not all from different groups.

```
edgeGroups = 
  Apply[DirectedEdge, {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 
      2}}, {{4, 1}, {1, 4}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 3}, {1, 5}}}, {2}];
```

Let us assign "colours" (integers) to the edges based on which group they are in:

```
colours = 
 Association@
  Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[edgeGroups -> Range@Length[edgeGroups]]]
```

Since we have this, we might as well visualize the graph with colours:

```
g = Graph[Keys[colours], 
  EdgeStyle -> Normal[ColorData[97] /@ colours], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Now we find all cycles:

```
cycles = FindCycle[g, {4}, All]

(* {{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 1}} *)
```

And keep only those where all the edges come from different groups:

```
Select[
 cycles,
 Length@Union@Lookup[colours, #] == Length[edgeGroups] &
]
```

I.e. we want to have 4 different edge colours in the cycle because we have 4 colours in total.